# Query in firebase usining angular 4 and angularFire 2

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I try to query a list from 5000 products that have property = 110571 is not do anything

I use angularfire 2 but for the last 5 hours, I don't get anything help me.

What is the best way to do that?

#### This is the object in Firebase database

```
 "products" : {

    1753: {
      "name" : "sprite",
      "custom_id" : 534253,
      "description" : "some small description"
    },

    1754: {
      "name" : "coca cola",
      "custom_id" : 110571,   <---- i want to find if this node from 5000 products exist in database and if exist i want to return true
      "description" : "some small description"
    },

    1755: {
      "name" : "fanta",
      "custom_id" : dsgfsdfds,
      "description" : "some small description"
    },

  }
```

#### This is the function that I use

> x = 1754;

```
check_if_product_code_exist(x) {

    console.log(x);

    this.searchSubject.next(x);
    // this.products = this.db.list('/products') as FirebaseListObservable<Product[]>;
    this.products = this.db.list('/products', { query: {
      orderByChild: 'custom_id',
      equalTo: this.searchSubject,
      limitToFirst: 1
    }} ) as FirebaseListObservable<Product[]>;

    console.log(this.products);
    return this.products;
  }
```

Comment: What is the current response?

Comment: Unless your subject is a `BehaviorSubject` or a `ReplaySubject`, you should call its `next` method *after* you create the list observable.

Comment: i manage to make aquery but is downloading 14Mb of data .and i dont want that i just want to check if a product code exist in database. i nead to wait 3 min after check